# ASP .Net Membership Access Rules

Tags: asp.net, membership, rules

Hi I have setup Access Rules on my local server and they work fine.  However when I deploy them on to my staging server the rules are not in effect.  Where are the rules stored?  Both my local and staging server point to the same DB server.  Thank you for any insight.

I set the Access Rules in the ASP.Net Web Application Administration

Answer (score 5):

Each secure folder has a `web.config` file that defines access rules of that path.
Copy them to your server.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean roles/users restrictions, those go in the web.config. The built-in roleprovider and membershipprovider store the users and roles in the db, but the allow/deny roles are in the web.config (or in custom code you do for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

The membership info is stored in the ASPNETDB database, which by default is in the app_data folder.   Check your web.config for the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```